# How to prevent leaving Excel worksheet before given numbers (let say 1-10) are in given cells (let say A2:A20)?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I am struggling with the worksheet_Deactivate and this is my what i got...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Dim rngCheck As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer


Set rngCheck = Me.Range("B10:B19")
```

Comment: What's the `Me` variable? You don't define it anywhere?

Comment: @PuravTheGreat `Me` is the reserved keyword in VBA for instance of a class object to refer to itself

Comment: Does it work in this case?

Comment: there is no `end sub` also..